# How to use previously trained data for new test data in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, gaussian, prediction, training-data

I use Gaussian process regression in Python. I have big data for training and try to predict test data. The trained data will not vary, but test data will. My question is that if it is possible to save the results of training and whenever new test data come in, just quickly predict the target of the test data without retraining all over again. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: Have you looked at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html?

Comment: Well there are several options which depend highly on your use case. You could for example serialize your trained model: you train once, and then store the whole trained object as binary data on your disk. Whenever you want to predict, you simply read the binary data and recreate your training model. A different approach is writing some kind of server, which always keeps the trained model in memory and awaits the input of new data to predict.

Comment: If you predict the training data with an object e.g. `clf.fit(X, y)` you might try pickle dumping the object with `pickle.dump(clf)`. This doesn't always work, but it might be worth a shot